# Connection refused (in socks5_connect() at socks5.c:202)

Tags: proxy, tor, socks5

Делаю прокси socks5 на базе tor браузера.
Сервер на Ubuntu.

**Файл torrc:**

```
SOCKSPort 9050

SOCKSPolicy accept *

SocksListenAddress 0.0.0.0

SocksPort 0.0.0.0:9050 PreferSOCKSNoAuth IPv6Traffic PreferIPv6

DNSLeakProtection 1

NewCircuitPeriod 30
```

**Файл torsocks.conf:**

```
TorAddress 127.0.0.1

TorPort 9050

OnionAddrRange 127.42.42.0/24
```

**При попытке выполнить команду:**

```
torsocks wget -qO - https://api.ipify.org; echo
```

**Получаю ошибку:**

```
1687341713 PERROR torsocks[1159]: socks5 libc connect: Connection refused (in socks5_connect() at socks5.c:202)
```

Пытался решить это настройкой конфига, спрашивал у тех, кто делал такие прокси, у chatGPT, гуглил. Все бестолку.

Может кто сталкивался и знает решение.